# Case Insensitive Compare with Core Data and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

The following code doesn't work:

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector:"caseInsensitiveCompare")
```

And gives the following error:
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unsupported NSSortDescriptor selector: caseInsensitiveCompare'

Seemed to work fine in Objective-C. Any ideas on why this might be?

Edit: seems like this may not be possible with Core Data/SQLite. In that case, is the best option to get the array and sort it in code afterwards?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The selector is `caseInsensitiveCompare:`, with the colon, and you can use it with Core Data.

The colon is there because the method (which is an instance method of `NSString`) takes one argument (the string to compare with).

As list of sort selectors which can be used with Core Data and a SQLite
store can be found in
[Persistent Store Types and Behaviors](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/PersistentStoreFeatures.html) in the *Core Data Programming Guide*.

Answer (score 52):

Swift 3 - 5.0 Syntax

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "KeyName", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare))
```

Comment: This syntax is required by Swift 3.

Answer (score 8):

Swift 5, SwiftUI syntax

```
self._contacts = FetchRequest(
            entity: Contact.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: [
                NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))
            ],
            predicate: predicate
        )
```