# NSSortDescriptor case sensitivity in Swift 4.2

Tags: nssortdescriptor, swift4.2

I am trying to sort alphabetically without case sensitivity using NSSortDescriptor is Swift 4.2. Unfortunately, I have only found solutions in Objective-C.

```
func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Entity")
    let sorter = NSSortDescriptor(key: "texttitle", ascending: true)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sorter]
    return fetchRequest

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case Insensitive Compare with Core Data and Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165986/case-insensitive-compare-with-core-data-and-swift)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using
`caseInsensitiveCompare:` (with the colon) does not work in Swift 4.2.

This works:

```
func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Entity")
    let sorter = NSSortDescriptor(key: "texttitle", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare))

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sorter]
    return fetchRequest

}
```